# CSS: Absolute objects in relative object, ignoring container flow

Tags: css, containers, positioning

from my point, the *fittedImageRight* and the *text* are two relative positioned containers, so why is the text ignoring the heigth of the *fittedImageRight* container?

I want to load different images, crop and center them, and the text beneath sould adapt to the heigth of the image.

I'm new to this, so i would appreciate any help.

```css
.text {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.containerRight {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}


.fittedImageRight {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.fittedImageRight img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.fittedImageRight img.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerRight">
  <div class="fittedImageRight"><img class="portrait" src="A.png"></div>
  <div class="font text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think, you need to add `overflow: hidden;` to class `.fittedImageRight`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text only below the image you dont need to float anything. If you float the div it takes it out of the flow of the page that is why its not recognizing the height of the container. Also if you want the image container to adjust to the height of the image you need to remove the height or set it to auto.